# What are the dots below a lint warning and how to I hide them?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The dots are below `user` and `amount`:

[image: code with dots]

When I hover over them, I get this:

[image]

Note that I do not want to solve the lint warning—I want to hide/disable all dots.

Comment: Hiding warnings, any kind of warnings, is seldom a good idea. Fixing the problem is a much better way to "hide" the dots. What's your reasoning for hiding the the warnings instead of fixing them?

Comment: Taking a screenshot for a presentation, and want the code to be concise / don't want characters that are superfluous to my point.

Comment: While you managed to solve the problem on your own (great! :) ), please always include the actual problem you're trying to solve in the question itself. It can help viewers to post perhaps quick and dirty workarounds (which, quite honestly, your solution is), that can then easily be disabled for a proper fix later (and please always do proper fixes rather than relying on quick and dirty hacks or workarounds, in the long run it will make the code better).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your intention for this is specifically about taking screenshots or videos rather than day-to-day work, I suggest that you start by getting some "Presentation Mode" extension (there are a few in the Extension store, not recommending any).

These extensions make it easy to apply a set of UI customizations while you are in presentation mode, then reset those customizations when you leave presentation mode. That saves you time and makes it less likely that you forget to reset your settings when getting back to work.

By default, most of these extensions will perform some or all of the following customizations: increase font size, remove scroll bars, hide status bar, nav bar and other panels, select a specific color theme, execute some commands, etc. Most also allows you to specify custom color theme modifications to enable while you are in presentation mode.

As you already found out, the setting for that specific decoration is `editorHint.foreground`, but you may also want to have a look at `editorInfo`, `editorWarning`, `editorError`, and `editorUnnecessary` all of which produce similar visual decorations. To hide a decorator, make sure to set its color's alpha to 0, rather than matching the color of the background, so that it remains hidden even if the background turns out to be different that what you expect (eg. text is selected).

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to settings worked:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorHint.foreground": "#00000000"
  }
```